# Drawing polar vectors with HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Edit:  Solved.  Switched Math.asin() for Math.atan2().

I'm trying to draw a polar vector (radius, angle) to a point on a canvas with JavaScript given the X,Y coordinates gotten by a mouse click.  This seems simple, but so far I haven't gotten it to work.

What I've done:

```
window.onload=init();
var canv, ctx, H, W;
var A, th;

function clickAction(e) {
    var pos=getMousePos(e);
    var x=pos.x;
    var y=pos.y;
    var A=Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y);
    var th=Math.asin(-y/A)*(180/Math.PI);

    drawVec(x,y);  //draws a line to (x,y) from center
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0,0,50,0,th); ctx.stroke();

    console.log(x,y, th);
}

 function init() {
    canv=document.getElementById("canv");
    ctx=canv.getContext('2d');
    H=canv.height;  W=canv.width;

    ctx.translate(W/2, H/2);
    drawAxes();

    canv.addEventListener('mousedown', clickAction);    
}
```

The arc should go from the x-axis (angle=0) to wherever you clicked, going counterclockwise (angle=theta).  But it's not. And drawAxes(), drawVec(), and getMousePos() are straight-forward and working so I didn't include them.

Thanks.

Comment: A represents the distance, not the angle. You need to use Math.atan2(diffY, diffX) to get the angle.

Comment: Could you provide a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Ken Fyrstenberg:  I think that did it, thanks.